# Is it possible to access environmental variables outside of wsgi's application function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wsgi

How can I access the environmental variables of my web app outside of the `application (environ, start_response)` function?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass `environ` to your functions... That's the reason why it's provided to the `wsgi` callback.

Comment: I don't get it, can you please explain more

Comment: Assuming you're not talking about what you could get from `os.environ` but about the environ variables passed by the `wsgi` protocol (http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/#environ-variables), the way to make it available to your "web app" (which you didn't take care to explain how it was coded) is to pass it to the functions that you call from your `application` object or callable (cf http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/#the-application-framework-side).